# How to parse numbers more strict than what NumberFormat does in Java?

Tags: java, validation, number-formatting

I'm validating user input from a form.

I parse the input with [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html), but it is evil and allow almost anything. Is there any way to parse number more strict?

E.g. I would like to not allow these three inputs, for an integer, but `Numberformat` allow all of them:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
nf.setParseIntegerOnly(true);

Number numberA = nf.parse("99.731");    // 99 (not what the user expect)
Number numberB = nf.parse("99s.231");   // 99 (invalid)
Number numberC = nf.parse("9g9");       // 9  (invalid)

System.out.println(numberA.toString());
System.out.println(numberB.toString());
System.out.println(numberC.toString());
```

Comment: how about converting it to a string and then loop over the string and allow only characters "0".."9"? or just go for getIntegerInstance();

Comment: @DorinDuminica: `getIntegerInstance()` gives the same result.

Comment: why not use `Integer.parseInt(String)`

Comment: This question is unclear.  You do not state precisely what formats should be allowed ... or whether you want to accept "locale sensitive" integer formats.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

> The NumberFormat classes that come with the JDK don't allow for strict number parsing. This has been filed as an enhancement here: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6431200 where a workaround is listed.
>
> > "Use a ParsePosition to get the index after parsing. If ParsePostion.getIndex() != string.length(), then parse() didn't consume the entire string."
>
> Actually, you can also add a check to make sure the error index is -1. Values other than -1 mean that there was an error. Trimming the value before parsing is also a good idea. The end product might look something like this:

```
String value = "number_to_be_parsed".trim();
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
Number parsed = formatter.parse(value, pos);
if (pos.getIndex() != value.length() || pos.getErrorIndex() != -1) {
    throw new RuntimeException("my error description");
}
```

(Thanks to [Strict number parsing at mynetgear.net](https://web.archive.org/web/20081005102148/http://shrubbery.mynetgear.net/wiki/Strict_number_parsing))

Comment: Thank you - this is the only realy solving answer! The other do not consider local (like decimal delimiter). Just wondering why the hell this is not (at least configureable) in the default implementation :(

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do that:

- regex - check if it `matches("\\d+")`
- with `javax.validation` - [`@Digits(fraction=0, integer=5)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Digits.html)
- apache commons `IntegerValidator`

Answer (score 2):

`Integer.parseInt(String)` will throw a NumberFormatException on all of your examples.  I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, but it's definitely "more strict."

Answer (score 0):

Use DecimalFormat with a format pattern string.

Comment: `DecimalFormat` has the same problem with this. Or do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at DecimalFormat that is a subclass of NumberFormat http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###.###");

Comment: This gives the same evil result.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use java's number format routine, especially with the locale settings if you worry about validation.

```
    Locale numberLocale = new Locale(“es”,”ES");
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(numberLocale);
    ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
    Number test = nf.parse("0.2", pos);
```

You would expect there to be an issue here, but no..  test is equal to 2 and pos has an index of 3 and error index of -1.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on writing my own validation class, and went with [**NEBULA WIDGETS** *FormattedText*](https://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/formattedtext/formattedtext.php)

It was written over the SWT widget API, but you can easily adapt the [NumberFormatter class](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula/blob/master/widgets/formattedtext/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.formattedtext/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/formattedtext/NumberFormatter.java)